Qual é a origem da expressão "não há de quê"?
A expressão é usada como resposta para um agradecimento. Como na situação abaixo:
- Onde fica a praça?
- Em frente ao banco.
- Obrigado
- Não há de quê

Às vezes, os espanhóis também dizem a mesma coisa na Espanha: no hay de qué (em vez de de nada).

@tchrist Não seria "em vez de gracias".

Trata-se da forma abreviadada de "não há de quê agradecer". Também é usada a expressão "não tem de quê".
